# Using checkbox to perform print action

Tags: forms, ms-access, checkbox, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm creating a database for a preventative maintenance program for the equipment in my facility. We have about 70 different machines with individuals preventative maintenance instructions, and I've been able to create tables for machines with the instructions attached to them by using forms that will update the database.

I created a main form that will filter which PM needs to be done based on the date that is searched that will filter through the machines in the database, access does this fine. The problem I'm currently having trouble with is finding a way to add checkboxes to this main form, and print off only the ones that are selected with a button. The plan we have is to have the mechanics to be able to print off the PM instructions, and use the print off to update the database. Is there a way this can be done with checkboxes or optionboxes?

Here's a picture of form without an checkboxes in it.

[image]

Here's a picture of the form view of where the user will input information that will update the database. WE're trying to get this to print out by using checkbox in the form that will search for the PM instruction

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is definitely doable - IMHO it would be a combination of setting the [click event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845501.aspx) in the boxes to contain code explicitly stating [PrintOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192667.aspx) functions specific to the pages you want to print out given a specific box ticked.